# Update model value in boot script by id in loopback?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs

I'm using this code in one of my server boot script-

```
var server = require('../server');
var ds = server.dataSources.mysql;

var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var router  = express.Router();

module.exports = function(app) {

app.get('/test',function(req,res){
    //console.log(server.model);
    server.models.Company.update({
        filter: {
            where: {
                id: 1
                },
            },
        },
        name: 's12'
    });
});
};
```

the problem is it updates all row in the database. How should I make this function so that it updates name where id is 1.

please help me into this.

Comment: which ORM are you using in 'server' ? sequelize ?

Comment: @JeromeWAGNER loopback

Comment: sorry i don't use loopback and can't find any "update" method in the documentation - https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-updateall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jerome WAGNER is right when he says there isn't an `update` method - it's `updateAll`. Furthermore you shouldn't use the full filter syntax for non query methods, and you need to include a callback method. [From the docs](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter#Wherefilter-Whereclauseforothermethods):

> When you call the Node APIs for methods other than queries, don't wrap
>   the where clause in a `{ where : ... }` object...

So your example should be:

```
app.get('/test',function(req,res){
    //console.log(server.model);
    server.models.Company.updateAll({ id: 1 }, { name: 's12' }, function(err, info) {
        ...
    });
});
```